# VBA: Error when trying to add data to the end of a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have this snippet of code to:

1. Copy data (offset for the header row)
2. Check to see if the destination workbook is open, if it isn't then open it
3. Go to the end of a sheet of that workbook and add the copied data.

   ```
   ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).Copy




   Dim WbookCheck As Workbook

    On Error Resume Next
    Set WbookCheck = Workbooks("PL Template Alpha v2 2-20.xlsb")
    On Error GoTo 0

   If WbookCheck Is Nothing Then 'not open....

   filepaths = "c:\documents\PL Template Alpha v2 2-20.xlsb"

   If Dir(filepaths) = "" Then
       MsgBox "File name does not exist"
   Else
       'file exists - open it
       Set WbookCheck = Workbooks.Open(filepaths)
   End If
   End If


   Workbooks("PL Template Alpha v2 2-20.xlsb").Sheets("DATA").[a1].End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).paste
   ```

However, I keep getting an error on execution (on the last line) - is there an issue in my code somewhere?

Comment: On which line of code does the error occur ??

Comment: On the last line - sorry about that `Object doesn't support this property or method`

Comment: This is just a guess, try capitalizing paste at the end of the last line.  make it end in .Paste

Comment: What is the value of [a1] ?

Comment: @dev1998 fortunately, VBA isn't case sensitive in that regard and when it is, it will autocorrect the case. `[a1]` is the first cell in the worksheet. It is a starting reference point from which to go to the end of the worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, try this:
Get rid of:`Workbooks("PL Template Alpha v2 2-20.xlsb").Sheets("DATA").[a1].End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).paste`

and add this in it's place:

```
Set Sht = WbookCheck.Worksheets("DATA")

Sht.Activate
Range("A1").end(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

You may need to adjust the Range and the Offset in case it is not pasting where you want it, but it pasted for me without any errors.

Comment: Nice, this worked for me! Not sure what the issue was with the original code, but thanks a ton.